# How to Combine Laravel Blade Directives to Check Form Input Fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

When working with Laravel Blade, I can check for form input errors using the Blade "@error()" directive:

```
@error( 'name' )
    {{-- Do something. --}}
@enderror
```

However, is there a way I can check for multiple errors to specific input fields?

```
@error( 'name' ) || @error( 'email' ) || @error( 'phone' )
    {{-- Do something. --}}
@enderror
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@if ($errors->hasAny('name', 'email', 'phone'))
    ...
@endif
```